# Flume HDFS Sink Customized Output

Tags: flume

I am trying to use Flume with hdfs as sink. File is getting exported. But I want to customize the name of the output file. I am using hdfs.filePrefix property for it. It is still creating a file with filePrefix.timestamp. how can I remove this timestamp from this.